# Using a RST Document in a ScrollView using Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am in a bit of a predicament. While working with Kivy's ScrollView Layout and (Current Experimental) reStructuredText renderer module, I ran into a slight problem. Whenever I run my code, my terminal spams me with:

```
[CRITICAL] [Clock] Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame. Check your code, or increase the Clock.max_iteration attribute
```

Now, the application seems to run perfectly fine, until you get to the page with the rST Document inside a ScrollView Layout. That page does all kinds of odd things. The Main scroll view will slowly scroll down, forever, trailing off the page into whiteness, and the rST document is placed oddly, shifted slightly to the left.

When I remove the document though, the screen and application behave perfectly normal, running smoothly. Does anyone have any idea as to how I could fix this, to make the page work correctly? (Did I mention the rST Document was originally in a Carousel, but I took out the carousel to see if that was the problem.)
Here is the Kivy Language Code:

```
<Page>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: (.99, .99)
        StackLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            id: content_layout
            height: self.minimum_height
            WrappedLabel:
                text: "Test"
                font_size: min(root.height, root.width)
            RstDocument:
                underline_color: 'blue'
                text:("Some Text")
```

Could the problem be that rST Documents are based off of the ScrollView Layout by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes `height: self.minimum_height` and similar stuff are like shooting yourself in a foot. Definitely try to comment out these things first, because if you don't do something fancy, the sizing is the issue.

Now, why is it an issue? [`StackLayout`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/stacklayout.py#L105) has its `minimum_height` set from `minimum_size`, which is set I think somewhere [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/stacklayout.py#L213) and has some initial value that is *not* zero.

Don't be confused though, `minimum_height` really defaults to zero at the beginning, but then it's recalculated probably on each added widget or so. If you add `on_height: print(self.height)` after your `height: self.minimum_height`, you'll see what I mean.

Why does it do it like that? Simple! You didn't set absolute size for those children (each child has `size_hint == [1, 1]`).

Also, `ScrollView` expects size bigger that the ScrollView if I remember correctly (so that it would scroll).

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
Builder.load_string('''
<Test>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: (.99, .99)
        StackLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            id: content_layout
            height: self.minimum_height
            on_height: print(self.height)
            Label:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 100, 30
                text: "Test"
                font_size: min(root.height, root.width)
            RstDocument:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 100, 1000
                underline_color: 'blue'
                text:("Some Text")
''')
class Test(BoxLayout): pass
runTouchApp(Test())
```

Remove `size_hint` and `size` from children and you have your `too much iteration` there.