# Critical Clock warning too much iteration with Kivy RST editor

Tags: kivy, restructuredtext, kivy-language

In a larger application I have in a separate screen a kind of rst editor. As soon as I type a character in the input widget, I get an ongoing list of Critical Clock Warnings:
[CRITICAL] [Clock       ] Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame. Check your code, or increase the Clock.max_iteration attribute

I have increased the max-iteration attribute but that does not solve the problem. Also in the code below, it does not make any difference if I set the size or not.

How could I solve this problem?

The edit screen file:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from functools import partial

Builder.load_file('editscreen.kv')

class EditScreen(Screen):
    '''Screen class.'''

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(EditScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def updaterst(self):
        inptext = self.txt_inpt.text
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.do_update, inptext), 0.1)

    def do_update(self, text, *args):
        self.rsttxt.text = text
```

and the kv file:

```
# File: editscreen.kv
#: import editscreen editscreen

<EditScreen>:
    name: 'EditScreen'

    txt_inpt:txt_inpt
    rsttxt:rsttxt

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        #size_hint: (.99, .99)
        TextInput:
            id: txt_inpt
            #size_hint: None, None
            #size: 400, 400
            on_text: root.updaterst()
        RstDocument:
            id: rsttxt
            #size_hint: None, None
            #size: 400, 400
            show_errors: True
```

Comment: As for "[CRITICAL] [Clock] Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame. Check your code, or increase the Clock.max_iteration attribute", please refer to another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448755/using-a-rst-document-in-a-scrollview-using-kivy

Comment: I followed this post as you can see in my code example. See also my comments in the item below.

Answer (score 1):

## size_hint: (None, None)

To change the sizes, you have to add the following into your kv file. Please refer to the app below for details.

### Format

```
widget.size_hint = (width_percent, height_percent)
```

### Examples

```
size_hint: (None, None)
size_hint: (1, None)
```

## App Example

### editor.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from functools import partial


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class EditScreen(Screen):
    '''Screen class.'''
    txt_inpt = ObjectProperty(None)
    rsttxt = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(EditScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def updaterst(self):
        inptext = self.txt_inpt.text
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.do_update, inptext), 0.1)

    def do_update(self, text, *args):
        self.rsttxt.text = text


class EditorApp(App):
    title = "Kivy RichText Editor"

    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    EditorApp().run()
```

### editor.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<MyScreenManager>:
    EditScreen:

<EditScreen>:
    name: 'EditScreen'

    txt_inpt:txt_inpt
    rsttxt:rsttxt

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        # size_hint: (.99, .99)
        TextInput:
            id: txt_inpt
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: root.height / 2
            on_text: root.updaterst()
        RstDocument:
            id: rsttxt
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: root.height / 2
            show_errors: True
```

### Output

[image: App with text input]

Comment: Dear Ikolim, thanks for your detailed reply. Unfortunately this does not solve my problem. The Critical Clock warning remains. My guess is that it has something to do with the combination of using a Tabbedpanel for primary navigation and a screenmanager within the tab context. So I will dive into this matter.

Answer (score 1):

I just edited a bit your code and it worked fine no critical warning:

-py:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.app import App


class EditScreen(Screen):
   '''Screen class.'''
   txt_inpt = ObjectProperty()

   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      super(EditScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
      Clock.schedule_interval(self.do_update, 0.1)

   def do_update(self, *args):
      self.rsttxt.text = self.txt_inpt.text

class EditorApp(App):

   def build(self):
      return EditScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   EditorApp().run()
```

-kv:

```
<EditScreen>:
   name: 'EditScreen'

   txt_inpt:txt_inpt
   rsttxt:rsttxt

   BoxLayout:
      orientation: 'vertical'
      #size_hint: (.99, .99)
      TextInput:
         id: txt_inpt
         #size_hint: None, None
         #size: 400, 400
      RstDocument:
         id: rsttxt
         #size_hint: None, None
         #size: 400, 400
         show_errors: True
```

output:

[image: no warning]

please try my code and tell us

Comment: Your code example works fine in my environment as well as a single app. But integrated in my total package it keeps on generating these Critical Clock warnings.

Comment: I understand the problem. the pb was the on_text event handler so remove it and schedule an interval looping rather than an once. I updated my code, try it with your large code. I hope i helped !

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Unfortunately this solution does not solve the problem either. I am pretty sure that it has something to do (read: bug) with the use of Tabbedpanels for main navigation in combination with screenmanager. I am starting redesigning the navigation structure and will make use of screenmanager only and a lazy loading architecture. Once finished I will post the outcome here.

Comment: Ok, but since nothing works to help you properly we need more of your code.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about the buttons. If there are many buttons in a row and go beyond the screen, if it is reduced, then an error occurs. I put size_hint: None, None and it worked. use FloatLayout for positioning buttons and other elements. Set the size in dp, sp so they don't run over each other. make apps for big screens.